# Roboelectric with databases in android

Tags: android, robolectric

Has anyone tried to test databases with roboelectric? I have to pass the context to create the database but I don't know how to inject it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It wont work easily since the db is on device... and robolectric runs on the jvm mocking all device related stuff out. I would recommend to use Robotium for that instead.

If you still want to somehow do this with Robolectric you will have to get a sqlite db running and connecting to it on the jvm from the robolectric tests.

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/robolectric/gSeC9r5zqr0

Good one for testing the content provider with robolectric, but we have to call the content provider queries directly as content resolver wont be there.

Comment: I am using ShadowContentResolver to make queries to ContentProvider with Robolectric